# Is it safe to charge lithium ion batteries that are in series individually?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, series

I have a 3S1P lithium ion battery pack that I'm making.  I wanted an easy and convenient way to charge the battery pack, so I was going to add a battery charging IC to the battery pack and charge the battery pack through USB C (no power delivery.) Since USB base voltage is 5V, I wanted to know if it would be safe to charge my 3S1P pack with each cell having its own dedicated charging IC.

[image]

Comment: Yes, as long as they are floating. If your chargers share ground, you'll have a short circuit,

Comment: And if they are all powered from the same USB, they share the same ground.